# Segfault while looping

Tags: c++

Working through a simple problem, but getting a segmentation fault because the program is writing past the end of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

static const int N = 46350;

int main()
{
    int* intarray = new int[N];

    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
    {
        intarray[i] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (intarray[i])
        {
            for (int j = i; j*i < N; ++j)
            {
                printf("before i: %i j: %i ", i, j);
                std::cout << "a: " << intarray + i*j << std::endl;
                intarray[i*j] = 0;
                printf("after  i: %i j: %i ", i, j);
                std::cout << "a: " << intarray + i*j << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    delete [] intarray;
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
before i: 211 j: 219 array: 0x21dd24c
after  i: 211 j: 219 array: 0x21dd24c
before i: 46349 j: 46349 array: 0x2488aec
```

This doesn't happen for N = 46349. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer overflow is causing this. The product of `i` and `j` overflows the range of type `int` and produces a negative value, which obviously compares as "less than `N`". Later you attempt to modify memory at that negative index `i * j`, which leads to unpredictable results. In fact, the overflow itself is already producing undefined behavior.

For this value of `N` you can get away with using `unsigned int` type instead of `int` type. The former has two times larger positive range. But in general case you have to remember that a product of two `int` value does not necessarily fit into the range of `int` type.

In your case `i` can become as large as `46349` and 46349 * 46349 = 2148322500, which is greater than the typical upper limit of signed 2's-complement 32-bit integer 2147483647.

The version with N=463549 is formally also broken in the very same way, except that you got lucky with that version. The `if (intarray[i])` check prevents the inner cycle from running in situations where it would lead to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum integer (`int`) in your case is `2^31-1`, which is `2147483647`. The square root of that number is `46340.95...` So when you multiply `i * j` you are getting an integer overflow, the result looks negative, and it appears to be `< N` and is allowed through in the loop. So you get a fault. So really, anything above `46340` and you could have some problems.